# ClassNotFoundException for JUnit tests in AspectJ project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, aspectj, classnotfoundexception

Google has some answers for this, but they are all for people using Maven. I am not using Maven so I am stumped. I have other projects that are not using the AspectJ plugin and their JUnit tests run fine in Eclipse. I cannot figure out why Eclipse cannot find the class. I right click on the class itself and then I tell it to run as a JUnit test. It works for JUnit tests in my non-AspectJ projects. Can anybody help?

```
Class not found BasicSpectrogramPeriodogramTests
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BasicSpectrogramPeriodogramTests
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace so people can better diagnose what the problem is?

Comment: ClassNotFoundException? of which class....what errors does Eclipse give you?

Answer (score 1):

Previously I faced similar issue and problem was because of broken build paths to external libraries (e.g. Selenium server). So first of all please open Build path (right click project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path) and verify that all external libraries can be loaded successfully (there are messages like 'cannot load'). Most likely a library was renamed/moved while optimization or adding external tools like Ant. Hope this helps

WBR, Andrey

Answer (score 0):

The AspectJ plugin may be influencing your build classpath but not the runtime classpath.  Create a launcher entry for your class and then explicitly set the classpath to include the jar.

Use Eclipse's 'load type' function to see where it is loading the class from.

Ctrl-Space-T pulls up a dialog. Enter the target classname, "BasicSpectrogramPeriodogramTests
".  It should display the package name and location in the workspace, either to the right of the classname for all listed classes, or near the bottom of the dialog for a selected class.  This will include the jar and its path if that is how it is being loaded by Eclipse.

Make sure the path for your class is what is in the runtime config classpath.  Add it explicitly at the top of the classpath, even it it is a dup.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by create a launcher entry. I have a run configuration for the class as a JUnit Test Case. Which jar are you referring to? I tried adding the JUnit-4.5.jar to my Classpath, but it didn't change anything. It was listed in the default classpath too.

Comment: The run configuration is what was meant by launcher. The jar meant whichever jar contains the class mentioned in the exception - "BasicSpectrogramPeriodogramTests" in this case. I'm not as familiar with AspectJ or JUnit-4.5 so I wouldn't know which specific jar contains that class.

Comment: The project containing the class is in the classpath. I do not have a jar that contains the class.

Comment: @Bluebomber - which classpath, the build classpath or the run config classpath.  Have you verified the .class file exists in the projects output folder? Sometimes it gets cleaned or out of sync. Are you using a project reference to include the class?  Try explicitly populating the runtime classpath, don't rely on the default.

Comment: Is the build classpath the classpath set by right-clicking the project->properties->Java Build Path? I used that build path and added the source folder with my JUnit .class files, and now it works. I still don't see why the other Java projects that I inherited from other people run JUnit tests and don't appear to do this same step.

Comment: It must be something about how it is an AspectJ Eclipse project and the other projects I inherited do not use the AspectJ plugin.

Comment: Apparently my little fix above does not solve all my problems. I still have to rebuild by the command line using my antfile.xml, and then I have to Project->clean to get the JUnit .class file to update! Something really screwy must be happening because of the AspectJ plugin.

Comment: Well I finally decided to just remove the AspectJ capability from my Eclipse project and bam, now JUnit doesn't give me any more trouble. This has all been very bizarre. If anybody has any insights, let me know.

Comment: @Bluebomber - Maybe it had an older copy of JUnit it was loading before your local copy.  Plugins have to do that sort of thing when they depend on jars.  Because the classloader for AspectJ loads its copy of JUnit first, any (newer) classes that appear later in the classpath are ignored.  If you're up for one more experiment, try placing the AspectJ reference at the very end of the runtime classpath.

Comment: In my run configuration for my JUnit test, I have all my jars in under User Entries in a single project. The "Up" and "Down" buttons to the right are greyed out and I cannot change the ordering. By runtime classpath, do you mean the classpath tab in the run configurations for that JUnit test?

Comment: Select 'User Entries' and add a new jar, point to the JUnit.jar; you should be able to move that entry so it's listed before the project.  That should make Eclipse load your specific JUnit jar first.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't make a difference. I just noticed that for some reason, when I convert my project to AspectJ, it wants to look in my bin folder for the JUnit .class files. When I convert it back to normal, Eclipse has no trouble finding the .class files in my testbin folder. I am really confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: It might be a bug of AspectJ.  Do they have a support forum for things like this?  Maybe a bug tracker?  It's worth a look.